# In Python, is this a good practice?

Tags: python

```
try:
    spam.foo
except AttributeError:
    do_somthing()
```

(Is it wise to check an attribute like that without using it?)

Comment: If the attribute is a property, and the property has side-effects, this can be devastating.  Why do you need to know if a property exists?  You have the source.  Why not read the source?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**:

If you are really only interested in whether the attribute `foo` exists (and not doing something with the attribute) than of course `hasattr()` might be better way to check for the attribute.
From a *developer/user* point of view I have to confess that, for me, the use of `hasattr()` better reflects your intention. And besides that it would result in less code:

```
if not hasattr(spam,'foo'):
    do_something()
```

The documentation of `hasattr()` describes that it is implemented by:

> (This is implemented by) calling `getattr(object, name)` and seeing whether it raises an exception or not.

So basically `hasattr()` does exactly the same as you are doing. In this case I would definitely go with the build in solution, i.e. `hasattr()`. You won't gain any speed advantage.

---

Python encourages the [**EAFP** paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Exceptions):

> It is Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission

So yes this is exactly the way one should do this **if** you more or less know that `spam` will have a `foo` attribute most of the time (the code will be (little?) faster).
Otherwise, if `spam` does not have a `foo` attribute (most of the time), then this approach would be better:

```
if hasattr(spam, 'foo'):
    bar = spam.foo
else:
    do_somthing()
```

The section on Wikipedia I linked to describes this. Quote (where the *EAFP version* refers to the way you wrote your code sample):

> These two code samples have the same effect, although there will be performance differences. When **spam has the attribute** eggs, the **EAFP** sample will **run faster**. When spam **does not have the attribute** eggs (the "exceptional" case), the EAFP sample will **run slower**. (...) If **exceptional cases are rare**, then the **EAFP version** will have **superior average performance** than the alternative.

Which is somehow obvious as (with EAFP) you don't have to introspect the object every time before you want to access the attribute.

Comment: @felix Is this still the case in my case (where I'm not using the attribute at all in the "try" context)? Is it still considered Pythonic?

Comment: I think `try...catch` is bad idea. Avoid them if you can even if `It is Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission` .

Comment: @orokusaki: why would you need to do it if you're not using the attribute? If you're testing to work out what type of object it is, then no, that's not considered Pythonic. Instead it's typical to use the object in the way you were hoping to use it and handle any exception that results. Better still, examine why you have a function that takes a variety of objects with disparate interfaces.

Comment: It's a higher order function that checks the attribute for existence and alters the function if it's not set.

Answer (score 2):

Better use

```
if hasattr(spam,"foo"):
   #dosomthing with spam.foo
else:
   do_somthing()
```

Python docs:

> hasattr(object, name)
>       The arguments are an object and a string. The result is True if the
>   string is the name of one of the
>   object’s attributes, False if not.
>   (This is implemented by calling
>   getattr(object, name) and seeing
>   whether it raises an exception or
>   not.)

Comment: If you want to check for `spam.foo`, you would use `hasattr(spam, "foo")`. `hasattr(spam, foo)` assumes that `foo` is a variable holding a string, and checks `spam` for the attribute named by the string.

Comment: +1 for your answer. I chose Felix' answer because if a visitor finds this question, I think it's important for them to understand both angles. With his answer it's now less of a "which to use?" and more of a "use the interface for style, or use the implementation for speed?".

Comment: @orokusaki: I updated my answer again. Your code is exactly the way `hasattr` is implemented (I noticed this now). So I would go with `hasattr` as you probably don't get a measurable speed advantage.

Comment: @orokusaki That is exactly what I thought :) and have already given felix +1 for considering both the angles. ;)